# Change opacity of lines

Tags: matlab, plot, opacity, alpha

I want to change the opacity of lines I plotted in a figure in MATLAB. I read somewhere about alpha and facealpha commands but couldn't figure how to use them. Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  MathWorks Support Team on [How can I set the transparency of LINE objects in MATLAB 7.14 (R2012a)?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2STXLP/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-2STXLP) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170130230713/http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103074-how-can-i-set-the-transparency-of-line-objects-in-matlab-7-14-r2012a)):

> Line series objects do not support transparency (alpha) values. The
>   following workaround can be used to overcome this limitation:
>
> 1. Please refer to the following MATLAB Central link:     http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m
> 2. The above function can be used to introduce transparency in LINE objects as follows:
>
> EXAMPLE 1:
>
> ```
> n = 10;
> xs = rand(n,1);
> ys = rand(n,1);
> zs = rand(n,1)*3;
> plot3(xs,ys,zs,'r.')
> xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
> p  = patchline(xs,ys,zs,'linestyle','--','edgecolor','g','linewidth',3,'edgealpha',0.2);
> ```
>
> EXAMPLE 2:
>
> ```
> t = 0:pi/64:4*pi;
> p(1) = patchline(t,sin(t),'edgecolor','b','linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.5);
> p(2) = patchline(t,cos(t),'edgecolor','r','linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.5);
> l = legend('sine(t)','cosine(t)');
> tmp = sort(findobj(l,'type','patch'));
> for ii = 1:numel(tmp)
>     set(tmp(ii),'facecolor',get(p(ii),'edgecolor'),'facealpha',get(p(ii),'edgealpha'),'edgecolor','none')
> end
> ```

[`patchline.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline/content/patchline.m) (by Brett Shoelson, 20 Jun 2012 (Updated 01 Sep 2016)):

```
function p = patchline(xs,ys,varargin)
% Plot lines as patches (efficiently)
%
% SYNTAX:
%     patchline(xs,ys)
%     patchline(xs,ys,zs,...)
%     patchline(xs,ys,zs,'PropertyName',propertyvalue,...)
%     p = patchline(...)
%
% PROPERTIES: 
%     Accepts all parameter-values accepted by PATCH.
% 
% DESCRIPTION:
%     p = patchline(xs,ys,zs,'PropertyName',propertyvalue,...)
%         Takes a vector of x-values (xs) and a same-sized
%         vector of y-values (ys). z-values (zs) are
%         supported, but optional; if specified, zs must
%         occupy the third input position. Takes all P-V
%         pairs supported by PATCH. Returns in p the handle
%         to the resulting patch object.
%         
% NOTES:
%     Note that we are drawing 0-thickness patches here,
%     represented only by their edges. FACE PROPERTIES WILL
%     NOT NOTICEABLY AFFECT THESE OBJECTS! (Modify the
%     properties of the edges instead.)
%
%     LINUX (UNIX) USERS: One test-user found that this code
%     worked well on his Windows machine, but crashed his
%     Linux box. We traced the problem to an openGL issue;
%     the problem can be fixed by calling 'opengl software'
%     in your <http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html startup.m>.
%     (That command is valid at startup, but not at runtime,
%     on a unix machine.)
%
% EXAMPLES:
%%% Example 1:
%
% n = 10;
% xs = rand(n,1);
% ys = rand(n,1);
% zs = rand(n,1)*3;
% plot3(xs,ys,zs,'r.')
% xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z');
% p  = patchline(xs,ys,zs,'linestyle','--','edgecolor','g',...
%     'linewidth',3,'edgealpha',0.2);
%
%%% Example 2: (Note "hold on" not necessary here!)
%
% t = 0:pi/64:4*pi;
% p(1) = patchline(t,sin(t),'edgecolor','b','linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.5);
% p(2) = patchline(t,cos(t),'edgecolor','r','linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.5);
% l = legend('sine(t)','cosine(t)');
% tmp = sort(findobj(l,'type','patch'));
% for ii = 1:numel(tmp)
%     set(tmp(ii),'facecolor',get(p(ii),'edgecolor'),'facealpha',get(p(ii),'edgealpha'),'edgecolor','none')
% end
%
%%% Example 3 (requires Image Processing Toolbox):
%%%   (NOTE that this is NOT the same as showing a transparent image on 
%%%         of the existing image. (That functionality is
%%%         available using showMaskAsOverlay or imoverlay).
%%%         Instead, patchline plots transparent lines over
%%%         the image.)
%
% img = imread('rice.png');
% imshow(img)
% img = imtophat(img,strel('disk',15));
% grains = im2bw(img,graythresh(img));
% grains = bwareaopen(grains,10);
% edges = edge(grains,'canny');
% boundaries = bwboundaries(edges,'noholes');
% cmap = jet(numel(boundaries));
% ind = randperm(numel(boundaries));
% for ii = 1:numel(boundaries)
% patchline(boundaries{ii}(:,2),boundaries{ii}(:,1),...
%     'edgealpha',0.2,'edgecolor',cmap(ind(ii),:),'linewidth',3);
% end
%
% Written by Brett Shoelson, PhD
% brett.shoelson@mathworks.com
% 5/31/2012
% 
% Revisions:
% 6/26 Improved rice.png example, modified FEX image.
%
% Copyright 2012 MathWorks, Inc.
%
% See also: patch, line, plot

[zs,PVs] = parseInputs(varargin{:});
if rem(numel(PVs),2) ~= 0
    % Odd number of inputs!
    error('patchline: Parameter-Values must be entered in valid pairs')
end

% Facecolor = 'k' is (essentially) ignored here, but syntactically necessary
if isempty(zs)
    p = patch([xs(:);NaN],[ys(:);NaN],'k');
else
    p = patch([xs(:);NaN],[ys(:);NaN],[zs(:);NaN],'k');
end

% Apply PV pairs
for ii = 1:2:numel(PVs)
    set(p,PVs{ii},PVs{ii+1})
end
if nargout == 0
    clear p
end

function [zs,PVs] = parseInputs(varargin)
if isnumeric(varargin{1})
    zs = varargin{1};
    PVs = varargin(2:end);
else
    PVs = varargin;
    zs = [];
end
```

License:

```
Copyright (c) 2016, The MathWorks, Inc.
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
met:

    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
      the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    * In all cases, the software is, and all modifications and derivatives
      of the software shall be, licensed to you solely for use in conjunction
      with MathWorks products and service offerings.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```